# Convert factors in dataframes when loading RData object

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large `.RData` object that contains dozens of data frames and matrices. I was given this object and did not create it. When I load the data using `load(data = myfile.Rdata)` the data frames are full of pesky **Factors**. Is there an easy way to convert the factors in all these data frames to either `character` or `numeric` similar to how `read_csv()` differs from `read.csv()`? Running `tbl_df()` when I use each data frame will not do the conversions.

Here is an attempt at a minimal example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c('A','B','C','D'),
              B = c('-0.011','10','15','-45'))

save(df1, file = "sto_test.RData")

## Load and show class
load(file = 'sto_test.RData')
str(df1)
```

Comment: `mutate_each` or `mutate_all` with `as.character`, iterating over all the data frames, may do it. As far as I know, no one puts factors in matrices.

Comment: If you want the automatic conversion of `read_csv`, I would suggest using `read_csv`.  `load` the data, write them all out as CSVs using `write_csv`, read them all in with `read_csv`, save the results in a new RData object so you don't have to repeat.

Comment: @Frank I included the matrices bit mainly out of frustration, the question was meant to be about the data frames.